# Need Clarification on definition of supremum, infimum, upper bound, lower bound

Tags: real-analysis

I am bit confused regarding few basic terminologies suddenly. When we talked about terms like supremum, infimum, bounded above, bounded below for a particular set say $A$, are we considering a larger set in comparison to $A$ say set $B$ ( i.e. $A \subset B$ ). I am writing four sentences below, can you please verify which of them are mathematically correct ( or even make sense ) because that will ultimately help me to solve my confusion.

Fix " less than " relation on $\mathbb R$.

1. Set $(0,1)$ is bounded above in set $[0,1]$ ( upper bound is 1)
2. Set $(0,1)$ is not bounded above in set $(0,1)$ ( as there is no upper bound )
3. supremum of $(0,1)$ in $(0,1)$ does not exist.
4. supremum of $(0,1)$ in $[-1,2]$ is 1.

Thanks.

Comment: All four statements are correct.

Comment: All correct. Note that 3. follows from 2. The supremum, if it exists, is the least upper bound. There can't be a $least$ upper bound if there is $no$ upper bound.